# Atmel AT32AP7001-ALUT device not supported in Atmel Studio 7.0

Tags: avr, atmel, avr32, avr-studio7

I have a project for Atmel AT32AP7001-ALUT which was developed using avr32studio version 2.5 in the year 2008.

I have to implement new features for this project, I installed Atmel Studio 7.0 to start the development work. However Atmel Studio 7.0 does not seem to support for this device(AT32AP7001). I also tried to use avr32studio v2.5 but this software does not install for newer versions of windows. I searched for board support packages for AT32AP7001 to use it in Atmel Studio 7.0, but could not find any. I am new to embedded programming, can someone tell me how I can setup the project for this device in Atmel Studio 7.0?

Comment: I am using AVR studio 2.7 n win7 x64 without problems (and it is not conflicting with newer versions too). The only thing you need to do is to copy x86 program files contents to x64 folder so Eclipse and plugins will work as should. What windows you got (have not tested 8,10)? I hate Newer AVR studio versions as they discard native C++ support and the whole thing got huge slow to start and uncomfortable to work with (but that is my subjective point of view).

Answer (score 0):

The AT32AP7001-ALUT was [end of lifed](http://ineltek.com/eolpcnpdfs/WE122502.pdf) 2012/13, so you'll probably have a hard time finding new tool support for this device. Your best option is probably to install AVR32 Studio in a virtual machine running an appropriate version of Windows or Linux.